# python re.search regex - how to search for value in the last 4 digits of a string

Tags: python, regex

I have written a python script (my very first) that accepts input of a string and then uses re.search to create groups from the string for later use.

The input string would like something like this:

```
NSC_sdiakjfean=ffffffff3c19594d45525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660
```

The re.search I'm currently using is:

```
s = re.search('NSC_([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]*)=[0-9a-f]{8}([0-9a-f]{8})[0-9a-f]{24}([0-9a-f]{4})',name)
```

The problem that I've found is that sometimes the input I want to use is missing this section [0-9a-f]{24} so my python script crashes with an exception and doesn't capture the last group.

Is there any regex (yes I've googled this lots) that I can use for the last group start at the end of the input string and just group the last 4 digits?

Thanks in advance.

Adam

Comment: What exception do you get, exactly? (And BTW, `[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]` is wrong. You should put the dash at the end if you want to match it `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` matches the end of the string.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search("1234$","lkjlkj1234") # matches
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x6a10578>
>>> re.search("1234$","lkjlkj1234ff") # does not match
>>>
```

So the expression you may want is

```
s = re.search('([0-9a-f]{4})$',name)
```

Comment: Ok so using the $ at the end works, but how do i deal with the situation that some input strings might have 24 characters in before the last 4 digits and some might not? If I remove [0-9a-f]{24} it's fine for shorter strings but not the full length strings? if that makes sense?

Comment: Oh, right.  How about `s = re.search('NSC_([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]*)=[0-9a-f]{8}([0-9a-f]{8}).*([0-9a-f]{4})$',name)`?  Should capture both types of line.  If that doesn't work you can always test the binary value of `s` to see if it matched.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regexp to find the value of the last 4 symbols of a string, you can just use something like this:

```
s = 'NSC_sdiakjfean=ffffffff3c19594d45525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660'
print s[-4:]
```

Comment: He's attempting to make groups of datapoints for later reference that contain the entire line. What you describe will only give him the last four characters of the current string.

Comment: I didn't think about just slicing the string, even though I've done it before else where in the script..